# Get a list of contacts in a distribution list using php-ews API

Tags: php, outlook, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I am using PHP-EWS to get a list of contact. This list of contact is a distribution list in the Contacts root folder.

Actually I am using this:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password);


$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();

$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;

$request->ContactsView = new EWSType_ContactsViewType();
$request->ContactsView->InitialName = 'a';
$request->ContactsView->FinalName = 'z';


$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
 $request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::CONTACTS;

$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$response = $ews->FindItem($request);
```

I am able to get the ID of the Distribution List, but I can't get the emails address in it.
How could I get a stdClass Object of it or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the contacts inside of a contact group, you need to use the [ExpandDL operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa494152(v=exchg.150).aspx), passing the item ID of the contact group you want to expand. I'm not familiar enough with the php-ews library to give you sample code, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn629392(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection3) for an example of what the SOAP request looks like.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make it work on php. Thanks, I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: Good! It worked fine. Here is the code I used, in case someone had the same issue.
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password);
$request = new EWSType_ExpandDLType();

$request->Mailbox = new EWSType_EmailAddressType();
$request->Mailbox->ItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
$request->Mailbox->ItemId->Id = $myDistributionListId;

$response = $ews->ExpandDL($request);